# You are better than he. You are better than him

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions, sentence-meaning

> You are better than he.
>
> You are better than him.

Which one is correct?
According to my views,
Both are correct.
"HE"is correct according to examiners.
Otherwise, both are correct in conversation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are better than he.

You are better than him.

Both sentences are correct, without any difference in meaning. However, the former is very formal. Normally, you use the structure pronoun + verb after than such as you are better than he is.

The structure of the latter is used in informal English.

Answer (score 2):

> You are better than him

sounds more sensible, however if you insist on using `he` try it like this

> You are better than he is

Comment: You are better than he=You are better than he is.

Comment: Technically yes, but 'you are better than he' doesn't appear in conversation, as it would sound strange to most native speakers. Which examiners are not accepting 'you are better than him'? I've never heard of this, particularly considering the sentence suggested is very likely speech which follows slightly different rules to written English

Answer (score 1):

`than him` is correct.  This is because `he` is the subject form, which you don't use following a preposition.  `than he` technically should be followed by `is`, making the object of the preposition `is` which then links to a subject ( `he` ).